# Assign range to an array and paste data to the array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

i am very new to coding and recently attended a few beginner training to VBA. i started learning array and was thinking to assign a range to it and use this array in my excel function(copy paste) like below.. im sure thisis not the right way to do it since i got an error with my range...

```
Dim lastrow As String
Dim Myarr As Variant

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Myarr = ActiveSheet.Range("S6, U6, W6")
Range("D6").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Myarr & lastrow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: `Myarr = ActiveSheet.Range("S6, U6, W6")` is loading the array with  only one value, the value in S6

Comment: Can you not accomplish this with a simple formula? Why do you need VBA?

Comment: @braX `Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` one cannot copy formats with formulas.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code?

Comment: @ScottCraner craner im actually developing a macro and this code is actually copying a cell format from *D6* cell and paste it to multiple cells in this case i tried to use array.. and i want to paste to the last row of my data set and yes i do notice it only return with the value in S6..

Comment: @braX the manual of copying format is by format printer.. and i have like 20 plus cells to format every single time and data range is pretty huge. i do not want to format the whole column as well because it will interfere with my header which is why it starts with row 6..

Comment: So you want to paste the format of D6 into S6:Slastrow,U6:Ulastrow,...

Comment: @ScottCraner yes something like that.. and also to the last row of my data region under the column S6, U6 and etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to load the ranges as strings:

> `"S6:S"`

As the `&` concatenates a string.  So Lastrow being a number one needs to include the `S` for then end cell.

Also avoid using `.Select` it slows the code down.

You will also need to loop through the array.  It will not work as one shot.

```
Dim lastrow As String
Dim Myarr() As Variant
Dim str As Variant
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Myarr = Array("S6:S", "U6:U", "W6:W")
Range("D6").Copy
For Each str In Myarr
    Range(str & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Next str
```

Comment: @ScottCraner Couldn't we do something like `Union(.Range("S6:S" & lastrow), .Range("U6:U" & lastrow), .Range("W6:W" & lastrow)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` to do the paste of formats in one shot? I doubt this will make for any real improvements though, and readability is far better with a loop.

Comment: @RyanWildry if thats the case my code will be swarm with (range("??:?") as there are like 20 plus columns do this...

Comment: Yup agreed, loop is the way to go, but just pointing out there is a way (although not feasible here) to do the assignment of formats with non-contiguous ranges using union. More of a hey, this might be useful, it might be faster in some rare circumstances when assigning lots of formats, as this should be a touch faster.

Comment: @RyanWildry Yes or one could loop through the array and create a unioned range then apply the format in one shot.

Comment: @RyanWildry there are many ways, but my comment stating not possible in one shot is not to the placing of the format but the calling of the range itself.

Comment: @RyanWildry got you!  thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: @ScottCraner Gotcha, make sense. Thanks all.